# Save NSManagedObjectID in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an xcdatamodel with a set of entities built in a static library.

I am including this static library in a project. I would like to create another model in main project, with entity named Task. I would like to have an attribute in the entity where I could store the `NSManagedObjectID` of an entity created in static library. With `NSManagedObjectID` I could easily fetch the main store and get the entity.
In the end there could be many Task entities refer to an objectID.

Is it possible ? I also understand that this is sounds like a relational model, which Core Data isn't, so is there a better solution for dealing with the subject?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `NSManagedObjectID` is in itself not coding compliant. But you can get the URL representation of an object ID and store that. Like this:

```
myObject.externalTaskURL = [[task objectID] URIRepresentation];
```

Then in order to get the object ID back to retrieve the task object it refers to later *(`psc` is your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` where the `Task` entities live)*:

```
NSManagedObjectID* taskID = 
        [psc managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:myObject.externalTaskURL];
```

Make sure to **never** do this to a temporary managed object ID.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I will go for that. But do you know if there are any 'CoreData' solution for this ?

Comment: @Leonardo - There is not. You are supposed to have only one persistent store coordinator per application.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a managed object ID as a NSURL in a transformable attribute.